# Facebook api Unlike not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

When i issue an /1602545584_166697970146120/likes DELETE command i get the following response.
Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

Even with the graph api explorer:

> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 200
>     }
>   }

Will this be fixed or is it not possible to remove your like via the api (which i find ridiculous)

Comment: looks like your app has been flagged for spam or abuse, have you tried other post objects?

Comment: No, even with the graph explorer i get this, so its not my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Suddently it works again via the original method. Strange...

Method i used:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_appid,
  'secret' => FB_secret,
  'cookie' => false,
));
$facebook->setAccessToken($fbtoken);
$like = $facebook->api('/'.$postid.'/likes/','DELETE');
```

Answer (score 1):

The strange thing is that you're still able to post a like using graph, but you are unable to delete it. So you may be better off just leaving likes out of it since you're unable to delete a like and it will leave your app semi-functional.

Answer (score 1):

I observed that it works with the DELETE method ***on the condition that the unlike is being done to a proper post_id***.

My observations :

1) I made an unlike to a post_id of the format XXXXX_YYYYY that was posted by a PAGE : **It worked**.

2) I made an unlike to a post_id of the format XXXXX_YYYYY that was posted by a USER : **It did not work**.

3) I removed the XXXXX from the post_id of the format XXXXX_YYYYY that was posted by a USER : **It worked**. [ The XXXXX simplly denotes the user id ]

Comment: Where YYYYY is the post id? And XXXX as in target user id or the logged in userid

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is removed.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>
> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).

Comment: So that means you can only like, and not unlike items? Stupid

Comment: you can not even post you friends wall anymore with the new SDK